# Get all interface types in all assemblies referenced in project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application referencing in a solution couple of .NET Standard 2.0 projects. I want to use reflection and get all types and filter with specific interface implemented but it only returns the generic interfaces so the `IsHandlerInterface` method never return true.

```
List<AssemblyName> allAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                                        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                                                        .Where(p => p.FullName.StartsWith("Something"))
                                                        .ToList(); // I get 4 assemblies here with the correct results

List<Type> allAssembliesTypes = allAssemblies
                                      .Select(a => a.GetType())
                                      .ToList(); // Retrieving the types

List<Type> handlerTypes = allAssembliesTypes
                                            // typeof(ICommand).Assembly.GetTypes()
                                            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => IsHandlerInterface(y))) // Here I don't see the handler interface, only the generic ones, see method below
                                            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Handler")) // Maybe redundant
                                            .ToList();

private static bool IsHandlerInterface(Type type)
        {
            if (!type.IsGenericType)
                return false;

            Type typeDefinition = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            return typeDefinition == typeof(ICommandHandler<>) || typeDefinition == typeof(IQueryHandler<,>);
        }
```

A handler example below.

```
public sealed class SampleCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SampleCommand>
    {
        public SampleCommandHandler() // inject services
        {
        }

        public Task<Result> HandleAsync(SampleCommand command)
        {
            // command logic
            // preconditions handle
            // trigger events
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. can you show what IsHandlerInterface looks like?
2. why do you filter the interfaces both with IsHandlerInterface and with Name.EndsWith("Handler")? You seem to be filtering all types that inherit a "Handler interface" and after that, you filter all these types to those that end with "Handler" - aren't you overdoing something here?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's where the issue is, updated question with information.

Comment: "but it only returns the generic interfaces **so** the `IsHandlerInterface` method never return `true`" .. that is an illogical statement.  `IsHandlerInterface` will return `true` when the interface **is** a GenericType of type `ICommandHandler<>`.  Have you debugged this?

Comment: update your comments in your sample and description to reflect on your sample handler please.. which only has 1 interface, and therefore "// Here I don't see the handler interface, only the generic ones" is a point of confusion.  Your handler interface is a 'generic one' - your conditional checks reflect that.. and it will only ever be `true` if it is (regardless of the `typeof` checks).

Comment: I also have a concern with your `public sealed` class.  What is the usage here?  Are you defining this type in one of the 4 assemblies in `allAssemblies`? are you inheriting this type and part of the expectation here is to see the interface on the derived type?

Comment: Given this, [C# Interactive Screenshot Displaying GenericType and GenericTypeDefinition Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKp7V.png) I think your issue is out of the scope of what information you've provided, thus far.

Comment: Yes I have debugged it and never returns true since it seems that no interface type of *Handler is found in the returned types found in any assembly. Public sealed is just that nobody can inherit from and I believe it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: `.Select(a => a.GetType())` should use `GetTypes()`?

Comment: Found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code return all types that imelement `ICommandHandler<>` and `IQueryHandler<>`

```
var types = Assembly
    .GetEntryAssembly()
    .GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Select(s => s.GetType())
    .Where(p => typeof(ICommandHandler<>).IsAssignableFrom(p) || typeof(IQueryHandler<>).IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

Comment: Answer is correct but as a note I will comment that Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() will not work in AWS Lambda environment. See my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195633/122769

Comment: How is this even working? `s.GetType()` will just return the `AssemblyName` type...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get all assemblies with the referenced using with the below code.

```
List<Assembly> all = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
                             .GetReferencedAssemblies()
                             .Select(Assembly.Load);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() //Gets all the assemblies loaded
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()) //Gets all the types in each assembly
    .Where(t => typeof(IsHandlerInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t)) //filters out any type that can not be assigned IsHandlerInterface
    .ToList();//Creates a list of all types with the interface IsHandlerInterface
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person who's asking. Consider editing your answer to add an explanation and/or some more insight on why your solution is better than other ones. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).